# How to access user information from one servlet to many jsp in struts

Tags: java, servlets, struts-1

I want to access user information from wherever i needed, for example in one module i want to **edit the details**  of the user and in another module i want to **view the details** of the user. In this scenario i create one servlet to fetch the records for editing and once again i create a seperate servlet to fetch record for viewing. Could somebody help me out.

**View Module**

```xml
<action input="/Agent Mgt/View Agent/agent_view.jsp" name="AgentMgt" path="/agt_ctr" scope="request" type="Controller.AgentController">
    <forward name="agt_ctr_success" path="/Agent Mgt/View Agent/agent_view_fwd.jsp"/>
</action>
```

**Edit Module**

```xml
<action input="/Agent Mgt/Edit Agent/agent_edit.jsp" name="AgentEdit" path="/agt_edit" scope="request" type="Controller.AgentEditCtr">
    <forward name="agtEdit" path="/Agent Mgt/Edit Agent/agent_edit_fwd.jsp"/>
</action>
```

For editing records i use **agt_edit** controller, to fetch records i use **agt_ctr** controller. In editing module i fetched records from JSP and then i called the agt_edit in JSP. Since i know this is a bad practice i want to change this logic.

Comment: you could use a common helper class, or use inheritence

Comment: @Scary Wombat can you please explain it elaborately

Comment: Since this is Struts1, why did you tag it Struts2 ? Also stop using Struts1, *that* is the bad practice :/

Answer (score 0):

As you use struts (but do not forget that struts-1 is now obsolete as said by Andrea Ligios), you should have a MVC pattern.

The JSP is the view, the controller is the `Action` class and you should have services to allow the controller to access the data. With that separation, the different Action classes call same service to access the details of a user.